# .Net 1.1: asp.net photo gallery

Tags: asp.net

I don't know if you guys remember back in .Net 1.1 there is a ASP.net photo gallery web application on www.asp.net site.

Does anyone know what happen to the project? Is it dead? Where can i find the source code?

Thank.

p.s. I don't remember what the project was called. It was out at the same time the ASP.net personal website was released.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if you're thinking about the PhotoGallery Workspace on the old [GotDotNet site](http://www.gotdotnet.com)?

That site has been taken down now, but the author of the Project (if it's the same one you're thinking of) is Jason Gaylord.  He's got a working version of the gallery [on his site](http://www.jasongaylord.com/photos/).

That is the only one I can remember from that era.

Comment: I think that's it. I remember it was an stand alone project and seperate from the Personal website starter kit. I think the name is .Gallery or something like that. I wonder why it isn't in development anymore.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Is it the [Personal Site Starter Kit](http://www.asp.net/downloads/starter-kits/personal/)  ?

### Online Photo Gallery

- Easily add photos using built-in Web-based Administration system
- Group your photos by albums
- Random photo of the day on the front page

### Allow your friends to securely login

- You choose who to allow on your site
- Decide which albums are publicly viewable and which ones are private

### Technologies and Design Approaches Demonstrated:

- Databinding using DataList, FormView, and GridView controls
- Custom handler for fetching images from a database
- Two built in themes demonstrates a single-site multiple-theme architecture
- Security trimming using the menu controls

BTW, I found this by browsing to http://asp.net/ and typing "photo gallery" into the search box.

Also found: [Starter Kits and Community Projects](http://www.asp.net/community/projects/)

Comment: No. It was out at the same time as Personal Site Starter Kit but it is an stand alone project.